# BizTalk - Get Received and Send message count for each application

Tags: biztalk

I have a requirement where I need to get a received/sent message account by application in Biztalk.
I am able to get received/sent messages count by day but I have not been to somehow group it by its application. Does anyone have a query/script which can help?

I have googled and found a URL for BizTalk admin queries, but I think all those links have been archived and I cannot access them.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7960.biztalk-server-administrator-queries-and-scripts.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have found something which may help others. use below to get count of messages based on receive/send port.

```
use biztalkdtadb
SELECT COUNT(dbo.dta_MessageInOutEvents.dtTimestamp) AS MessageCount, BizTalkMgmtDb.dbo.bts_application.nvcName as ApplicationName
FROM dbo.dta_MessageInOutEvents WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN BizTalkMgmtDb.dbo.bts_receiveport WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.dta_PortName WITH (NOLOCK) ON BizTalkMgmtDb.dbo.bts_receiveport.nvcName = dbo.dta_PortName.strPortName ON
dbo.dta_MessageInOutEvents.nPortId = dbo.dta_PortName.nPortId
INNER JOIN BizTalkMgmtDb.dbo.bts_application WITH (NOLOCK) ON BizTalkMgmtDb.dbo.bts_receiveport.nApplicationID = BizTalkMgmtDb.dbo.bts_application.nID
GROUP BY BizTalkMgmtDb.dbo.bts_application.nvcName order by MessageCount desc
```